# High speed CAN configuration

Tags: can

Currently I am working on a project which needs me to configure the hardware from low-speed CAN (100 kbit/s) to high speed (@500 kbit/s).
The CAN controller supports baud rates up to 1 Mbit/s.

I am generating the configuration files using the VECTOR GENy tool. I have tried following configurations, but nothing seems to work out. Did I miss something?

Clock: 60 MHz, sampling 75%, prescaler = 8.

Clock: 60 MHz, Sampling 80%, prescaler = 5.

Clock: 12 MHz, sampling 75%, prescaler = 8.

Clock: 12 MHz, sampling 80%, prescaler = 5.

When I am using the above configurations, I am getting *No Ack* errors and bit errors. Do I need to modify the RX buffer and TX buffer?

Comment: With "low speed" do you mean fault-tolerant CAN? Or just lower baudrate?

Comment: "I am getting No Ack error" Are there other nodes on the bus? If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: Low baud rate CAN (100 Kbps).
There are no other Nodes, as its in Development state, I Know that's my problem, just wanna know if I missed anything .

Comment: Put the controller in loopback mode or preferably get a CAN listener. The latter is a must in the long run.

Comment: Ya that feature is available in the CAN analyser I am using.. will work on it.. Thanks.

Comment: CAN requires at least two active nodes configured with same baud rate on a bus. If you are transmitter, you need receiver who speaks at same baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website for your configurations:

http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/